# Understanding F# memory consumption

Tags: memory, f#

I've been toying around with F# lately and wrote this little snippet below, it just creates a number of randomized 3d-vectors, puts them into a list, maps each vector to its length and sums up all those values.

Running the program (as a Release Build .exe, not interactive), the binary consumes in this particular case (10 mio vectors) roughly 550 MB RAM. One Vec3 object should account for 12 bytes (or 16 assuming some alignment takes place). Even if you do the rough math with 32 bytes to account for some book-keeping overhead (bytes per object*10 mio) / 1024 / 1024) you're still 200 MB off the actual consumption. Naively i'd assume to have 10 mio * 4 bytes per single in the end, since the Vec3 objects are 'mapped away'.

My guess so far: either i keep one (or several) copy/copies of my list somewhere and i'm not aware of that, or some intermediate results get never garbage collected? I can't imagine that inheriting from System.Object brings in so much overhead.
Could someone point me into the right direction with this?

TiA

```
type Vec3(x: single, y: single, z:single) = 

    let mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)

    member self.Magnitude = mag

    override self.ToString() = sprintf "[%f %f %f]" x y z

let how_much = 10000000

let mutable rng = System.Random()

let sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
sw.Start()

let random_vec_iter len =

    let mutable result = []

    for x = 1 to len do
        let mutable accum = []

        for i = 1 to 3 do
            accum <- single(rng.NextDouble())::accum
        result <- Vec3(accum.[0], accum.[1], accum.[2])::result
    result

sum_len_func = List.reduce (fun x y -> x+y)
let map_to_mag_func = List.map (fun (x:Vec3) -> x.Magnitude)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "Hello, World"
    let res = sum_len_func (map_to_mag_func (random_vec_iter(how_much)))
    printfn "doing stuff with %i items took %i, result is %f" how_much     (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) res
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: first `sizeof<Vec3>` returns 8 (which seems reasonable) so there will indeed be much overhead - and this is the problem with garbage collected programs (like everything on .net) - it's really hard to measure the reals memory footprint (btw: how did you measure it? Is this just the value from the task manager or did you ask some memory profiler?)

Comment: Just looking at it you will produce lot's of temporary `accum` lists and stuff so it should be no big surprise if there are quite a few objects flying around to be disposed by the GC

Comment: for the total consumption i just looked at the value in the task manager. I now tried to the memory profiler of VS2013, the Vector class itself shows up with 12 bytes each (as expected), but the main chunk is used up by the list itself it seems. This might be the issue Daniel Fabian is pointing at. Still, why is the list still around anyway after i folded it to one value?

Comment: just did a quick memory-profiling (with 100 instead of 10mio) - at the end you will have 100 Vec3 (with 3200 Bytes) and 502 Lists (with 16.064 Bytes) - but also 187 strings (of 4.722 Bytes), some objects, ... - but you see the lists hit hard (and only 100 of em are from the Map - the rest are your mutable parts in random_vec_iter)

Comment: the lists will be grabed by the GC whenever it pleases ;)

Comment: for example if you add a `System.GC.Collect()` at the end (for example before the `ReadKey`) you most likely will find quite a smaller number (on my system its like 12MB)

Comment: "i just looked at the value in the task manager" that includes many one off overheads (eg. system libraries that are part of every process), and also many things that are not used (memory space allocated but never committed). You would be better looking at how Private Working Set perf counter (or [`Process.WorkingSet64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) changes with data size. Just remember that you are loading assemblies etc. to support complex programs: doing a few simple things doesn't really exercise them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your vec is a ref type not a value type (not a struct). So you hold a pointer on top of your 12 bytes (12+16). Then the list is a single-linked list, so another 16 bytes for a .net ref. Then, your List.map will create an intermediate list.